# In how many ways may 8 people form a circle for a folk dance?

Tags: permutations, combinations

So this was a worksheet on Permutations and Combinations that you can find online, which fortunately also provides the answers. However, I am concerned because the answer provided in class is different from the online key. Here is the question:

- *In how many ways may 8 people form a circle for a folk dance?*

For this question, can't you just factorial 8, which would be 40320 ? The student assistant in my class says that the order of the circle does not matter.

However, on the online key, the answer is ((8!)/(8))= 7! = 5040. Can someone explain how this is so?

Comment: How many people are required to form a circle?

Comment: Either the online key or your copying of it has a mistake.  $7! \neq 5014$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be $8!$ if it were a line of people, but a circle means there's no defined "start point" like there is with the line.

Since there are $8$ ways to "start" the circle, there are $\frac{8!}{8} = 7!$ ways to create a unique circle of people in terms of relative ordering (i.e. where rotations do not matter).

See also: [MathWorld: Circular Permutation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularPermutation.html)